# Installing Ubuntu on Windows 7

Tags: system-installation

After installing ubuntu on windows 7, does it looks like ubuntu have been installed on a virtual machine?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, if you install Ubuntu with Wubi, with the official disk/USB alongside Windows 7, you just have a dual-booted machine, so when you turn on your computer, you can select whether to run Ubuntu or Windows 7. You can't change between them without another restart.